# C++: What is the difference between std::shared_ptr<T> and std::shared_ptr<T const>?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

What is the difference between `std::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::shared_ptr<T const>`?

And when would you use one versus the other?

Comment: What's the difference between `T*` and `const T*`?

Comment: @MarkGarcia you left out `T const *` (which is redundant, tis true, but closer matches the form of the template params).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **`shared_ptr<int>`** is a `shared_ptr` to an non-const `int`. You can modify the int and the `shared_ptr`
- **`shared_ptr<const int>`** is a `shared_ptr` to a `const int`. You can't modify the `const int` the `shared_ptr` points to, because it's `const`. But you can modify the `shared_ptr` itself (assign to it, call other non-const methods, etc)
- **`const shared_ptr<int>`** is a `const shared_ptr` to a non-const `int`. You can't modify the `shared_ptr` (by calling `reset` or any non-const method), but you can modify the `int` it points to
- **`const shared_ptr<const int>`** is a `const shared_ptr` to a `const int`. You can't modify jack.

Comment: Is there a difference between `shared_ptr<const T>` and `shared_ptr<T const>`?

Comment: @kmccoy No. Just like there's no difference between `const int` and `int const`

Answer (score -1):

```
shared_ptr<T>
```

stores a T* under the hood, while

```
shared_ptr<T const>
```

stores a T const* under the hood. So it's the same as the difference between a pointer to some data and a  pointer to some constant data.

You would use a shared_ptr when you just want it to behave a like a regular pointer (with reference counting) and you would want to use shared_ptr when you want to store a ref-counted pointer to some constant data (data you never indend to modify.) Recall that there's a difference between a pointer to constant data (where you cannot modify the data pointed to, but you can modify the pointer) and a constant pointer (where you can modify the data pointed to, but not the pointer itself.) Finally there's a constant pointer to constant data, where you can neither modify the data pointed to nor the pointer itself.

Comment: `constant pointer to some data.` is wrong. It's a pointer to some const data.

Comment: Woops! It's late here. Edited.